# How does fgetc work internally

Tags: c, glibc, stdio, fgets, fgetc

Does it actually read character by character or does it read some bytes into the kernel buffer and return to the user- character by character?

Is it the same with `fgets`?

Let me say I use glibc and a gcc compiler.

Comment: This depends completely on your particular platform/C compiler/runtime/etc. The standard does not say. What platform are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost right. A typical modern implementation that does have a user/kernel separation stores the bytes **in a user buffer**, not in a kernel buffer. Thus many calls to `fgetc` actually trigger few true system calls.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Plenty of platforms (e.g. DOS) have no concept of a difference between the two. This is completely platform specific.

Comment: @BillyONeal True. But I think the OP already stepped out of the strictly standard-approved limits with this question anyways so it might make sense discussing the most common implementation.

Comment: What "most common implementation"? In terms of number of computers, there are a hell of a lot more tiny microcontrollers than full sized desktops in the world. And they don't have separation of userspace and kernel space. Nor do many RISCs. Simply put, the question as asked is not answerable. (Which is why I downvoted the question)

Comment: @BillyONeal I changed the wording, again :-)) I assumed this separation since the OP mentioned *kernel*.

Comment: @SharatChandra Then you could have mentioned `glibc` in your question.

Comment: @Billy: cnicutar said "a typical **modern** implementation". DOS is not modern.

Comment: @R.: It did not say that when I commented.